# Update Script to Populate empty fields

Tags: sql, excel, sql-update

I have empty cells in a sql table that I would like to populate at one time.  I have an excel spreadsheet with the corresponding numbers that need to go in the empty cells.  I would like to take the spreadsheet and use it to populate the empty cells in ssms.
[Excel Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6Rb1.jpg)

Based on what I've read I need to make an update script that will take the spreadsheet and say, "where you find a matching OBJECTID update the number from STAND_OPER_CODE(spreadsheet) to the STAND_OPER_CODE(SSMS)"

[SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M84B6.jpg)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68395052/edit) to include the code you have so far and what the problem is

Comment: I haven't used any code yet.  I know that it can be done in sql.  I just dont know how to do it.

Comment: Just from my very limited understanding it would be something like                     Update dbo.LRM_PRD_STAND
Set STAND_OPER_CODE = 3
Where OBJECTID IN (32236,
32859,
32860,
33366,
34367,
35035,
35078,
35460,
35473,
36428,
33353,
33354,
33359,
35323,
33363,
34322,
34323,
34324,
34325,
35083,
36709,
36710,
36711,
);                                                                                                                                            The point being take all of these numbers and put a 3 in the stand_oper_code column